# React File input not opening file browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am encountering a very strange error in my React application. I have this code:

```
<input
  accept="image/*"
  onChange={doUpload}
  type="file"
  name="fileUploader"
  id="photoUploader"
  ref={fileRef}
/>
```

but when I click the input to select a file, I don't get the file explorer at all. I also noticed that some of my form's `onSumit` did not fire until I added an `onClick` handler to the submit button.

Comment: what is the value in {fileRef}. Try with just ref="upload" and see if issue happens.

Comment: add `this.` before doUpload

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wow, found the bug. I had an `event.stopPropagation()` somewhere in a nested component.

Comment: Spent a lot of time figuring this out. Thanks!

Comment: So there is `event.preventDefault()` or `event.stopPropagation()`. I believe you ment to say one of those.

Comment: nice catch @laszlo-horvath, I'VE UPDATED IT

Answer (score -3):

You have to add this keyword. I hope it is useful for you:

```
       <input
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={this.doUpload}
          type="file"
          name="fileUploader"
          id="photoUploader"
          ref={this.fileRef}
        />
```

Comment: I'm using functional a component and my ref is defined as `const fileRef = useRef(null);`.